# React - append DOM infinitely without max depth / infinite loop errors?

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop

This maybe be counter to the essence of React, but... can I update the DOM infinitely?

i.e. I want to run something like this until I kill the app. Adding a STOP button would be nice, but I can CTRL+C in the console.

```
x=1;
while(x > 0){
  // append DOM with `<div>${x}</div>`
  x+=1;
}
```

I'm using useRef for the DOM container and have tried putting the logic in a useEffect hook but React doesn't like open-ended updates.

Comment: Why? Depending on what the goal is, there's several techniques for doing similar things, like infinite scrolling, that might be helpful. Depending on just how big the DOM gets, you may also need some virtualization.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very intrigued as to your use case. It would be good to know more about it as this request is an odd one. But I like the challenge so here I go.

React has infinite loop detection but you could do this by making sure that DOM elements are added only after each of the previous ones have been committed to the DOM.

```
import { useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";

export default function InfiniteDivAppender() {
  const [divCount, setDivCount] = useState(1);
  const [pause, setPause] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (pause) return;
    setImmediate(() => setDivCount((prev) => prev + 1));
  }, [divCount, pause]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setPause((prev) => !prev)}>
        {pause ? "Resume" : "Pause"}
      </button>
      {[...Array(divCount).keys()].map((n, index) => (
        <div key={index}>{index}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Note this is still an insane amount of browser ops and you'll likely need to wait for a few seconds for the tab to catch up, but it does print eventually, and it also does not trigger the loop detection because I'm using `setImmediate` alongside `useLayoutEffect` (note: not `useEffect`).

Note Ctrl+C on the console probably won't save you from a crashed browser tab -- it will crash eventually with this because you can't have infinite nodes on a web page.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this with an infinite loop useEffect. It looks like it gives you an error in the console about maximum depth, but it seems to still run?

[image: Edit gallant-rain-y7925k]

```
import "./styles.css";
import {useState, useEffect} from "react"

export default function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    setArray([...array, "hi"])
  }, [array])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {array.map((_, i) => <h1 key={i}>#{i}</h1>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It wont run infinitely, due to the max depth error -- which is his requirement.

Comment: This works but has max depth error in console.